# How to combine groups to create a single pair-wise comparison in meta-analysis?

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

for example, study report smokers as current, smoker, a former smoker, and occasional smoker, how can we combine smokers with occasional smokers to create one group. 
Cochrane has given method but it s mainly for the RCT and only reports adding the total sample and total events from the 2 groups to generate one group.

I am doing prognostic study meta-analysis. I have only total sample size for the study and event rate (for the study not for the each group), odd ratio and confidence rate

Kindly if someone can advise me how to combine 2 groups to create one group

Comment: When you say you have the total sample size and event rate for the study does that not answer your question? What exactly are you trying to combine?

Comment: e.g. I have a study with sample size  n = 2000, # of event/ with new condition= 200 
I have a predictor “current smoker” (OR = 1.6 (1.3, 2.1)]
ex smokers = [or (1.3 (1.1, 1.5)] 
I do not have  sample size and event sample for smokers and sample size for the ex- smokers  among the whole 2000. 

Is there a way where I can combine, both group based on the OR and CI? 
Cochrane reported a method:  combine number of patients from both categories and calculate effect based on those numbers. But as I mentioned, I do not have sample with and without event in each group.